# android rendering images in surface view with volley image loader

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-volley

I am running a SurfaceView as described here:

[Ref link](http://android-coding.blogspot.de/2011/05/drawing-on-surfaceview.html)

The SurfaceView is basically a thread and renders images asynchronously.

Inside the surface view I call volley's ImageLoader (which is a member of the the SurfaceView)
to asynchronously get images from a server.

The problem is that I receive the following stacktrace:

```
01-30 18:23:19.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6809): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3929
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be invoked from the main thread.
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.throwIfNotOnMainThread(ImageLoader.java:467)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:189)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:171)
```

Is there any way to have images requested from within the SurfaceView or there are alternative ways of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is done intentionally so that Volley doesn't return anything to the main thread which has already been destroyed (by for example destroying the application)